# Open a text file and getting average not working getting zero division error

Tags: python

I am a college student and we have an assignment I am struggling and can't find help. My code is not working and keeps telling me my average is getting zero division error. I rechecked my code and seems like the data from text file is not being used even though I open it. When I put total = 1 and count = 1, it gives me the average of 1. But if they are both zero that is when I get the zero division error.
Here is my code:

```
# This program was created to process the file of gas prices to determine the
# average gas price.

# Initalize the variables

count = 1
total = 1

# open file

gas_prices = open("gasprices.txt", "r")

# loop to process entire file

for price in gas_prices:

    # change price to float

    num_price = float(price)

    # count and increment inital
   
    count = count + 1
    total = total + num_price

# close file

gas_prices.close()

# calculate average

average = total / count
```

I check again and still can't find why the text file is not processing if I have the loop.

Comment: what is the content of gasprices ? is it like this one?https://github.com/selvathiruarul/gas_prices/blob/master/gas_prices/GasPrices.txt

Comment: ```average = total / count if count not == 0 else 0```

Comment: Could you show us what your `"gasprices.txt"` file looks like?